# Unable to connect dialogflow using environment variable in local env

Tags: java, dialogflow-es

I created a simple dialogflow intent.
I want to consume it from java application in local environment (Linux).
I get the error :

> The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.

I set environment variable like this :

```sh
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/me/******.json"
```

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-dialogflow</artifactId>
      <version>0.99.0-alpha</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String projectId = "my-project-id";
        String sessionId = "fake_session_for_testing";
        String languageCode = "fr-FR";
        List<String> texts = Arrays.asList("hello", "Qui tu es");

        Map<String, QueryResult> result = detectIntentTexts(projectId, texts, sessionId, languageCode);

        result.forEach((s, q) -> System.out.println(s + " " + q));
    }


    public static Map<String, QueryResult> detectIntentTexts(
            String projectId,
            List<String> texts,
            String sessionId,
            String languageCode) throws Exception {
        Map<String, QueryResult> queryResults = new HashMap<>();
        // Instantiates a client
        try (SessionsClient sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create()) {
            // Set the session name using the sessionId (UUID) and projectID (my-project-id)
            SessionName session = SessionName.of(projectId, sessionId);
            System.out.println("Session Path: " + session.toString());

            // Detect intents for each text input
            for (String text : texts) {
                // Set the text (hello) and language code (en-US) for the query
                TextInput.Builder textInput = TextInput.newBuilder().setText(text).setLanguageCode(languageCode);

                // Build the query with the TextInput
                QueryInput queryInput = QueryInput.newBuilder().setText(textInput).build();

                // Performs the detect intent request
                DetectIntentResponse response = sessionsClient.detectIntent(session, queryInput);

                // Display the query result
                QueryResult queryResult = response.getQueryResult();

                System.out.println("====================");
                System.out.format("Query Text: '%s'\n", queryResult.getQueryText());
                System.out.format("Detected Intent: %s (confidence: %f)\n",
                        queryResult.getIntent().getDisplayName(), queryResult.getIntentDetectionConfidence());
                System.out.format("Fulfillment Text: '%s'\n", queryResult.getFulfillmentText());

                queryResults.put(text, queryResult);
            }
        }
        return queryResults;

    }
}
```